# How to prevent IIS from idling .NetCore API for Hangfire

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

I have a published .NET Core 2.0 API in production hosted through IIS. 
This API has a hangfire dashboard and a single recurring job running through it.

This API exposes a service layer to us developers for jobs that we need to perform on certain databases so it is not always being hit with traffic - perhaps only occasionally when a dev hits an endpoint. The Recurring job runs hourly.

My Problem: Once the site receives no traffic for a while IIS idles the app effectively killing my hangfire job - I know this because in the dashboard when I click servers it says 0. As soon as I hit an endpoint on the API it spins back up.

What I've tried so far: In IIS Set startmode to AlwaysRunning and set the idle timeout to 0 for that specific application pool.

I know this is not working because every morning when I come into the office I check Kibana for logs that should be constant throughout the night due to the recurring hourly job but unfortunately nothing happens. As soon as I hit the API everything starts working again and the job queues.

Comment: Thread on timeouts with dotnet core https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/522